# Capistrano deploy:migrate to database inside vpn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, vpn, amazon-vpc

I am new to capistrano and rails.  I have setup my production environment in AWS within a AWS VPC.  My database can be accessed only within the VPC (by the web app and other nodes inside it).

I run my deployments from my local machine.  Is there any way to make capistrano run db:migrate from the remote machine instead of my local machine itself.

Also when doing normal cap production deploy, capistrano should not try connecting to my db machine.

I wasted almost a day in this.  Any help is appreciated.  I can provide more details if required.

Answer (score 0):

This is default task. Just run:

```
cap deploy:migrate
```

for more take a look at https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/Capistrano-Tasks

or you can try to add task to your deploy.rb:

```
desc "rake task"
task :rake do
  run "bash -l -c 'cd #{current_release}; \
      sudo `which rvm` `rvm current` do rake #{ARGV[1..-1].join(' ')} RAILS_ENV=production'"
  exit
end
```

and run like this:

```
cap rake db:migrate
```

Comment: when i do cap production deploy:migrate from my local, it tries to connect to the database specified in config/deploy/production.rb.  But my db can be accessed only inside vpn.  Capistrano should ssh to my web node and then do db:migrate.  How to do that?